# Can an analytic function take a simply connected region to a non simply connected region?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a function who is analytic $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and let $R$ be a simply connected open region in $\Omega$. Is $f(R)$ simply connected?

Comment: Nope. In fact there is an entire example (i.e. $R = \mathbb{C}$). Can you find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $R$ be an open disc centered on the real line such that it doesn't contain $0$.

If $f(z)=z^n$ for a large enough $n$, the image of $R$ under $f$ will wrap all the way around the origin, and so no be simply connected.

---

(Or, perhaps simpler to reason about, if $R$ is the upper half-plane, $z\mapsto z^3$ will map it onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$).

Comment: Oh good point...

Answer (score 4):

$f(z) =e^z$ takes the whole plane to the punctured plane.

Comment: wow, looks a lot like my answer.

Comment: You are right; my answer is the same as yours with less details.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\Omega = \{z:\Re(z) > 1\}$ and $f(z)=z^3$.

Answer (score 0):

iConsider a strip $S:=\mathbb R \times (y,y+2\pi] $. Then $e^z $ maps $S$ to $\mathbb C-{0}$. Or consider the image of $\mathbb C$ itself under the same $e^z$. In general, re Picard's theorem ,any entire function with lacunary values will be an example.